# transition width from center of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a div transition its width (enlarge) but I want it to grow from the center not the top left

HTML

```
<div id="attach-wrap">
        <div id="attach">

            ... content ...

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS
    #attach-wrap { min-height: 50px; }

```
#attach { 
  height: 50px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease; 
}

#attach.stick { 
  height: 80px; 
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

'.stick' gets added when certain conditions are met and thus animates it. Everything works perfectly except when .stick class gets added and animates the height and width, it is done from left to right. I want it to come from the center. It shrinks from the center when .stick class is removed, not sure why

Comment: I'd recommend using http://codepen.io  to set up a complete (failing) example. This helps people tinker with your code and you'll get an answer quicker.

Comment: tried making it but can't seem to get it to work at all, here is what I tried http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbOeKm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `position:fixed` from `#attach.stick`. That should allow it to scale like you expect.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/9n1sjame/) (Click the box to toggle)

If you require `position:fixed`, always give `#attach` an explicit margin, and also animate the margin ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/stsgveLz/2/)):

```
#attach {
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 20%;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.35s ease, height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.35s ease, height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
    -ms-transition: margin 0.35s ease, height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: margin 0.35s ease, height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
    transition: margin 0.35s ease, height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
}

#attach.stick {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: removing it would solve the centering issue, HOWEVER I need to keep position:fixed. I can't put it on #attach because then it would always be fixed (removed from the flow) I need it to be regular until scrolled to then fixed to top

Comment: @user3550879 I think the second part of my answer should work for you if you put the `position:fixed` in `#attach.stick`. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: that it does, no idea how, but it does

Comment: @user3550879 It does it by also transitioning the margin. At the same time that the width is increasing, the amount of space between the left of the block and the edge of the screen is decreasing at the same speed.